# Why are these 2 hebrew letters appear connected in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, hebrew

can anyone tell me why do the hebrew letters א, ל appear connected in the following page:
http://www.beneathhelmet.com/telaviv/

I tried everything, but I could not fix it, nor could I reproduce it on a different page. I tried changing the font, but it did not work...

this bug only appears in chrome, not other browsers.

Comment: This would have been a good question if it included a reproducible case (and explained clearly where issue is to be seen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. My theme included the following css rules:

```
-webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1, dlig=1";
  -ms-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
  -o-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
  font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
```

[apperently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings), this property enables advanced typographic features.

who knew...